# Overstriking into equation with Soul

Tags: equations, greek, soul

I need help to figure out how overstriking work into equation on Latex.

```
\documentclass[book]

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{soul}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\st{$ \gamma $} = \frac{\gamma}{2\pi} = 42.58 \text{ Mhz/T}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please, provide complete small document with your equation starting with `\doumentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Welcometo TeX.SE

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't use the facilities of the [soul](http://ctan.org/pkg/soul) package to strike out math-mode material. Instead, load the [cancel](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/cancel) package and use either `\cancel`, `\bcancel`, or `xcancel` to "cancel out" the term(s), as needed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cancel,siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\cancel{\gamma} = \frac{\gamma}{2\pi} = \SI{42.5}{Mhz/T}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: A follow-up comment: If, for some reason, you couldn't load the `cancel` package but yet could load the `soul` package (and the `amsmath` package too), I suppose you could get by with writing `\text{\st{$\gamma$}}`. However, you'd get a horizontal strike-out, which may not be easy for your readers to notice. That's why I recommend loading the `cancel` package for math-mode material, as the diagonal strike-out characters will basically be impossible to overlook.